# How do I initialize waveskeeper object?

Tags: blockchain, wavesplatform

How do I initialize waveskeeper object in my javascript code? I want to use waveskeeper on my site

Answer (score 1):

it's automatically there if keeper is installed
you can add this in your code:
console.log(Waves)
console.log(WavesKeeper)
will give you the same object (meaning you can use ether one)
You can check if waves keeper is install with something like:

```
if(typeof Waves !== 'undefined'){
console.log('installed')
}else{
console.log('not installed')
}
```